# No Hallel in the seder?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, hallel

I used a reprint of an old haggada this year (I think it was [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EO88WE0)) on the second night.  Through the meal everything was as I expected, other than a few differences because the haggada is Egyptian and I'm Ashkenazi, which were easy to work around.

After bentching was where it got really strange.  The haggada had the third cup and שפך חמתך as expected, then it went right to לשנה הבאה בירושלים, the fourth cup, al hagefen, and חסל סדור פסח.  The inside back cover has sefirat haomer.  That's it.  No Hallel at all, except the parts during Maggid.  (I think they called לשנה הבאה בירושלים and the brachot before and after the fourth cup the "Hallel" section).

Where does this come from?  Hallel is mentioned explicitly in the mishna, I thought everyone says it.  Do they say it in shul and count that somehow (even though the mishna is pretty explicit not that way)?  But then when do they say Nishmat and Hallel Hagadol?

Picture of the pages, as requested.  I didn't do a good job taking the last picture, but you can still make it out (at least the Hebrew parts, maybe not the French.  The sefirat haomer page was also smudged to begin with.).  The only thing after this is a couple of pages about the Diskin orphan home, which obviously weren't in the original.
[image: picture of pages 30-31]
[image: picture of pages 32-33]

Comment: I have a Judeo Arabic Haggadah from Egypt and it's quite short. You will find a very interesting talk about this called "Joey Mosseri: The History and Evolution of the Pesah Haggadah in Text, Law & Custom" and can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3pl2mTIkZw

Comment: And i would like to know if i could obtain a copy from this haggadah form you :D

Comment: @Aaron sorry, I'd like to keep mine, but you can get it from somebody on amazon at that link in the question :)  You can also try contacting the Diskin orphan home, they reprint a different one every year, not sure if they still have more copies of this one.

Comment: @Heshy i meant via pictures and scans ;)

Comment: @Heshy Some say Nishmat and Hallel haGadol is for the optional fifth cup.

Comment: @Aaron pictures of the relevant pages are there, if you want I can send you more but everything else was pretty much standard, aside from some obvious typos like ויאמר לאברהם ידוע תדע instead of לאברם.  Anything in particular you're looking for?

Comment: Can anyone translate all that French?

Comment: @DoubleAA  for French I can help (;( if you accept)

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't speak French, but I'm pretty sure the Hebrew translation is right above it :)

Comment: Isn't it a Machloket how much to say?

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot Yes - see Pesachim 117b-118a. The arguments there revolve around "Birchas HaShir" (Yehalelucha vs. Nishmas) and "Hallel HaGadol" (Tehillim 136, 120-136, or 135:4-end of 136). But the Mishnah there clearly states to finish the rest of Hallel, i.e. Tehillim 115-118. Nobody argues on that. (Well, apparently the printers of this Haggadah did.)

Comment: If I may ask, where did you find this Haggadah?

Comment: @DonielF the Diskin Israel Orphan Home reprints an old haggada every year, my grandfather z"l used to buy them each year.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Oz V’hadar extended Mesivta Haggadah](http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/63/pesach), it’s a machlokes Rishonim as to whether we say Hallel HaGadol or not:

- According to the reading of Rashi and Rashbam, R’ Tarfon *adds* to the Mishnah when he says we say Hallel HaGadol. Many Rishonim, including Tosfos and Ra’avya accordingly hold that since it’s a Machlokes Amoraim as to what Hallel HaGadol *is*, that indicates that we pasken like R’ Tarfon.
- Many Geonim and Rishonim, including Rav Sa’adya, Rabbeinu Chananel, and the Ba’al HaMeor, understand that R’ Tarfon, who in their reading proposes Hallel HaGadol on a *fifth* cup, is arguing on the Mishnah. Since they’re arguing, the Halacha follows the majority opinion of the Mishnah which says *not* to say Hallel HaGadol.
- Still other Rishonim, including the Raavad, the Ramban, and the Ran, take a middle ground: the fifth cup is optional, and Hallel HaGadol is only said if one drinks the fifth cup.

You and I apparently hold like the first opinion, that we say Hallel HaGadol without a fifth cup. Perhaps the printers of that Haggadah held like the second opinion, not to say Hallel HaGadol, and also held that the regular Hallel is to be said in shul.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%94_%D7%91 והאמר רב משום רבי חייא כזיתא פסחא והלילא פקע איגרא, והלילא פקע איגרא - לקול המולת ההמון מההלל דומין כאילו הגגין מתבקעים שהיו אומרים ההלל על הפסח כדתנן לקמן (דף צה.) הראשון טעון הלל על אכילתו, so maybe the machlokess is where you do not have a korban pesach, do you carry on with the same minhag or is hallel said specifically on the Pesach

Comment: The question is mainly about omitting regular Hallel (Hallel Mitzraim), not only Hallel HaGadol (Ki Le'olam Chasdo). If your main answer is in the second half of the last sentence (i.e. no need to say it at the seder since they already said it in shul), I think this needs more discussion and sources.